# OOP Help! Missing requirement : self

Tags: python, oop

Hello everyone this is my first post. I am currently trying to learn python OOP. What I did here is to build an imaginary printing machine using OOP in python. But whenever i start the machine, or try to insert ink etc.

I get this error :

```
TypeError murekkepDoldur() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is my code :

```
class Makine : #This is where i def my printing machine class#

    def __init__(self):
        self.murekkep=100 #this means ink#
        self.şarj=100  #this means charge
        self.devir=0    #this means how many turns did machine worked#
        self.mevcutDergi=[]  #this means list of printed magazines#

    def calis(self): #this means the work function for machine#
        if self.murekkep>=10 and self.şarj>=5:
            print("Makine çalışıyor.")
            self.murekkep-=10
            self.şarj-=5
            self.devir+=1
        elif self.murekkep<10 :
            print("Yetersiz mürekkep!")
        elif self.şarj<5 :
            print("Yetersiz şarj!")
        elif self.devir==10 :
            a=input()
            print("Yeni dergi çıktı!\nDerginin adı : "+ a)
            mevcutDergi.append(a)
            self.devir = 0

    def murekkepDoldur(self):  #this means add ink function#
        if self.murekkep<=80:
            self.murekkep+=20
            print("Mürekkep dolduruldu!\nYeni mürekkep seviyesi yüzde 
",self.murekkep)

    def şarjDoldur(self): #this means charge battery function#
        if self.şarj<=95:
            self.şarj+=5
            print("Şarj dolduruldu!\nYeni şarj seviyesi yüzde 
",self.şarj)

    def mevcutDurum(self):  #this means show status function#
        print("Makinenin murekkebi % ",self.murekkep, 
              "\nMakinenin şarjı % ", self.şarj,
              "\nMakinenin devir sayısı : " ,self.devir,
              "\nMevcut dergiler : ",self.mevcutDergi)
makine1=Makine                    
while True :
    print("-"*30)
    print("Matbaa Makinesi v0.1\n",
          "Makineyi çalıştırmak için->1\n",
          "Murekkep doldurmak için->2\n",
          "Şarj doldurmak için->3\n",
          "Mevcut durumu öğrenmek için->4")
    print("-"*30)
    komut = int(input())
    if komut==1:
        makine1.calis()
    elif komut==2:
        makine1.murekkepDoldur()
    elif komut==3:
        makine1.şarjDoldur()
    elif komut==4:
        makine1.mevcutDurum()
    else :
        print("Hatalı komut girdiniz!")
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions about errors, first of all try to create a [mcve] that replicates the problem, and show it to us. Secondly copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* error output into the question itself. And then mark out where you get the error (with a comment) in the code. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create an instance of class `Makine` before calling a method.

The problem is in this line:

```
makine1=Makine                    
while True:
```

that should be:

```
makine1=Makine()
while True:
```

Then it will be happy to work.

Comment: thank god that worked. but i didnt get it why should i put those at there

Comment: @YasinOsman The symbol `Makine` is the *class itself*. `Makine()` creates an *instance* (an object) of the class.

Comment: To add a bit more depth to @Someprogrammerdude explanation: ``Makine()`` invokes the constructor method of the class, which is the ``__init__(self)`` method. Its purpose is to initialize a new instance of the class, making the required operations on its members. If the constructor has arguments, like ``__init__(self, data)``, then you'll have to create an instance passing the arguments like this: ``Makine(my_data)``.